# Access Violation when calling LockFileEx()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-locking

I have a FileMapping class that allows me to also lock a file for exclusive use by my process by using the Win32 API function [LockFileEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203.aspx).

```
bool FileMapping::lockFile(bool wait) {
    if (isFileLocked())
        return true;

    // We want an exclusive lock.
    DWORD flags = LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK;

    // If we don't want the thread to block, we have to set the appropriate flag.
    if (!wait)
        flags |= LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY;

    m_isFileLocked = LockFileEx(m_fileDesc, flags, 0, (DWORD) m_mappingLength, (DWORD) (((uint64_t) m_mappingLength) >> 32), NULL);
    return m_isFileLocked;
}
```

Whenever I get to the `LockFileEx()` call I get an access violation:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7466c2ec in tftpServer.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

The file handle `m_fileDesc` is definitely a valid handle (mapping the file into memory with that handle works) and `m_mappingLength` is just a `size_t` containing the length of the mapped file portion in bytes.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: The *this* pointer is null.  You are calling this method on a null FileMapping object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last argument is `NULL`, while it should be a pointer to a `OVERLAPPED` structure. The error about reading location 0x00000008 probably corresponds to the documented requirement that:

> You must initialize the hEvent member to a valid handle or zero.

Given the `hEvent` member comes after two pointers, in 32 bit compilation it'd be 8 bytes from the beginning of the structure. So `LockFileEx` is probably trying to read the hEvent member, and crashes.

Comment: Oops, I must have overlooked that. I now created an OVERLAPPED structure and pass its address to LockFileEx() and it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have just been bitten by the same oversight. It should be in **bold** in the MSDN docs! :)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the docs you link to:

> lpOverlapped [in, out]
>
> > A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure that the function uses with the locking request. This structure, **which is required**, contains the file offset of the beginning of the lock range. You must initialize the hEvent member to a valid handle or zero.

So your last argument is wrong.

Comment: Oops, I must have overlooked that. I now created an OVERLAPPED structure and pass its address to LockFileEx() and it works. Thank you for your help.  
I know about the problem with the 5th argument if `size_t` is 32 bits. That's why I cast it to an uint64_t first, so I have a 64 bit value to perform the shift with. I know that on a 32-bit platform this parameter should always be zero, but I wanted it work on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, that's why I went for the cast and the shift.